# submitting multiple forms with javascript

Tags: javascript

My script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function submitform()
{
  document.playsong.submit();
}
</script>
```

Submits the below form:

```
<form name="playsong" method="post" action="submit.php">
<input type="hidden" name="play" value="2009-05-19-3934.data">
<A href="javascript: submitform()">Play 1</A>
</form>
```

How can I change this so that I can have a series of links: <`A href="javascript: submitform()">Play 1</A>` That will submit the correct form without having to build a function to submit each form.

That is how can I make the function submit different various forms on the page dependent the link clicked.

Comment: Just use input type="submit" instead. Links should be links and inputs should be inputs. (And users should have to have JS on to submit a form). If you really want to have something that looks like a link submit a form - then use CSS to style the input. For that matter, it doesn't look like anything substantive us happening on the server anyway, so change from post to get and <a href="submit.php?play=2009-05-19-3934.data">

Comment: @David:  "Links should be links and inputs should be inputs", where do these rules come from and who is benefited by them?

Comment: @Anthony: From the land of non mixed race marriages probably.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordances http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/ http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/links.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:-

```
 function submitForm(form)
 {
      document[form].submit();
 }

 <a href="javascript:submitform('playsong')">Play 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build several links like

```
<form action="act1">
    <a href="#" onclick="goForm(this.parentNode); return false;">Play 1</a>
</form>
<form action="act2">
    <a href="#" onclick="goForm(this.parentNode); return false;">Play 2</a>
</form>
<form action="act3">
    <a href="#" onclick="goForm(this.parentNode); return false;">Play 3</a>
</form>
<form action="act4">
    <a href="#" onclick="goForm(this.parentNode); return false;">Play 4</a>
</form>
<form action="act5">
    <a href="#" onclick="goForm(this.parentNode); return false;">Play 5</a>
</form>
```

And make a js:

```
function goForm(frm) {
    if (frm != null)
        frm.submit();
}
```

There you go! =´p

Comment: Anchor Element nodes do not have a form property - only form controls do.